# Using findSimilarColor to set a Background on Excel file

Tags: java, excel, palette, poi-hssf, hssf

I'm having a little problem using the **findSimilarColor** on my java code.
I already read some articles from the stackoverflow that helps me get to the following code.

```
HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

HSSFPalette palette = wb.getCustomPalette();
// get the color which most closely matches the color you want to use
HSSFColor myColor = palette.findSimilarColor(226, 0, 116); //java don't recognize this color
// get the palette index of that color 
short palIndex = myColor.getIndex();
// code to get the style for the cell goes here
style.setFillForegroundColor(palIndex);

style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);  
style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER_SELECTION);
```

With that, I have no problem setting a color, except with the RGB color that I'm trying to use `(226, 0, 116)`.

For some reason, the color that show up when I open my excel file at the end is `RGB (128, 0, 128)`.

Does anybody have any ideas why is this happening? Or an alternative solution?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the color `(226, 0, 116)` defined in the object **palette**? You are asking for the color defined in **palette** that is closer to your requirement and seems that `(128, 0, 128)` is the closest.

Try something like:

```
HSSFColor myColor = palette.addColor(226, 0, 116);
```

instead of asking for a similar color.

Answer (score 2):

I just test your solutions and I get the "Could not find free color index" error. So I search a little and find out the following code to avoid this error.

```
HSSFPalette palette = wb.getCustomPalette();

palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.TAN.index, (byte)226, (byte)0, (byte)116);
cabecalho.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.TAN.index);
```

It seems that I couldn't add a color to the pallete because the palette was full, so with this code I was able to overwrite the "Tan.index" to have the RGB Color that I want.

I'll try to find a better solution, but in the meanwhile this will help a lot.

Thank you once more.